# How to retrieve only those records that have at least one associated record?

Tags: cakephp, associations, query-builder, cakephp-3.2

The data should show only the tenancies that contains data. In normal query normally I do this be right join.

I know `contain()` is left join on default but can contain be right join at all?

My query:

```
$properties = $this->find()
                ->select([
                    'Property.id', 'Property.company_id', 'Property.address1', 'Property.postcode',  
                ])
                ->contain([                    
                    'Tenancies' => function($q) {
                        return $q
                            ->select([
                                'Tenancies.id','Tenancies.property_id','Tenancies.created',
                                'Tenancies.stage', 'Tenancies.landlord_offer_sent', 'Tenancies.offer_letter_contract_id',
                            ])
                            ->contain([
                                'Tenants' => function($q) {
                                    return $q
                                        ->select([
                                            'Tenants.id', 'Tenants.stage', 'Tenants.tenancy_id', 'Tenants.holding_fee',
                                        ])
                                        ->where([
                                            'active = 1',
                                        ]);
                                    }
                            ])
                            ->where([
                                'Tenancies.active = 1',
                            ]);
                    }
                ])
                ->where(['Property.active = 1', $conditions])
                ->toArray();
```

e.g. I need to get read of nodes that tenancies that are null `'tenancies' => [],` and it should show only node 1.

Prints=>

```
(int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Property) {

        'id' => (int) 95,
        'company_id' => (int) 3,
        'address1' => '40 Arthur Street',
        'postcode' => 'LE11 3AY',
        'tenancies' => [],
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Property'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Property) {

        'id' => (int) 102,
        'company_id' => (int) 3,
        'address1' => 'Grace Dieu Court',
        'postcode' => 'LE11 4QH',
        'tenancies' => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Tenancy) {

                'id' => (int) 16,
                'property_id' => (int) 102,
                'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                    'time' => '2015-05-08T09:30:41+00:00',
                    'timezone' => 'UTC',
                    'fixedNowTime' => false

                },
                'stage' => (int) 6,
                'landlord_offer_sent' => false,
                'offer_letter_contract_id' => (int) 37,
                'tenants' => [
                    (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

                        'id' => (int) 16,
                        'stage' => (int) 7,
                        'tenancy_id' => (int) 16,
                        'holding_fee' => (float) 50,
                        '[new]' => false,
                        '[accessible]' => [
                            '*' => true
                        ],
                        '[dirty]' => [],
                        '[original]' => [],
                        '[virtual]' => [],
                        '[errors]' => [],
                        '[invalid]' => [],
                        '[repository]' => 'Tenants'

                    },
                    (int) 1 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
```

I have tried inner join `'joinType' => 'INNER'` but no luck:

```
class TenancyTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('tenancy');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Properties', [
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
            'className' => 'property',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Not possible via containments for `hasMany` associations

This cannot be done with containments, as `hasMany` ones are being retrieved via a separate query. Instead you'll have to add a proper join yourself, an `INNER` join (more portable than a `RIGHT` join) could do it if you want to restrict the results to only those that have associated `Tenancies`.

A simple `Query::innerJoinWith()` without conditions, and some grouping to avoid duplicates

```
$properties = $this
    ->find()
    // ...
    ->innerJoinWith('Tenancies')
    ->group('Property.id');
```

... and you're done, this will add a join like

```sql
INNER JOIN tenancies Tenancies ON Property.id = Tenancies.property_id
```

### `innerJoinWith()` works for all other types of associations too

For `belongsTo` and `hasOne` associations however, it *could* be done via containments, as for these types of associations, all data is being retrieved in the same query. To filter by those that have an associated record, just change the join type to `INNER`, like

```
$this
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'BelongsToAssociated' => [
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]
    ]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using innerJoinWith](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith)**

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I simply changed `contains` to `matching`.

It seems to be possible, see [Filtering By Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)